# BCP python library load function not working

Tags: python, sql-server, sql-server-2017, bcp

I need to load a huge pandas dataset into a ms sql server. Unfortunately the to_sql() method works very slowly even with 'multi' method . This is why I opted for a bulk copy method using the bcp library . Here is what I tried :

```
import bcp
conn = bcp.Connection(host='HOST', driver='mssql')
my_bcp = bcp.BCP(conn)
table_name = 'test17'
csv_filename= r'c:\temp\%s.csv' % table_name
df.to_csv(csv_filename, index=False, header=False, sep=';')
file = bcp.DataFile(file_path=csv_filename, delimiter=';')
my_bcp.load(input_file=file, table='QUANT_work..test17')
```

Here is the error  :

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\ABENHA~1\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_5112/883077605.py in <module>
----> 1 my_bcp.load(input_file=file, table='QUANT_work..test17')

C:\Apps\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bcp\core.py in load(self, input_file, table)
     58         else:
     59             raise DriverNotSupportedException
---> 60         load.execute()
     61 
     62     def dump(self, query: str, output_file: 'DataFile'):

C:\Apps\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bcp\dialects\mssql.py in execute(self)
     80         This will run the instance's command via the BCP utility
     81         """
---> 82         subprocess.run(f'bcp {self.command}', check=True)
     83 
     84     @property

C:\Apps\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bcp\dialects\mssql.py in command(self)
     90              the command that will be passed into the BCP command line utility
     91         """
---> 92         return f'{self.table} in "{self.file.path}" {self.connection} {self.config} {self.logging} {self.error}'
     93 
     94     @property

C:\Apps\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bcp\files.py in path(self)
     54     @property
     55     def path(self) -> Path:
---> 56         return self.file.absolute()
     57 
     58 

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'absolute'
```

Thanks.

Comment: What is the generated SQL code?

Comment: @RickJames How do I get the generated query ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a Path object instead of a string variable in bcp.DataFile.

```
import bcp
import pathlib
conn = bcp.Connection(host='HOST', driver='mssql')
my_bcp = bcp.BCP(conn)
table_name = 'test17'
csv_filename= r'c:\temp\%s.csv' % table_name
df.to_csv(csv_filename, index=False, header=False, sep=';')
p = pathlib.Path(csv_filename)
file = bcp.DataFile(file_path=p, delimiter=';')
my_bcp.load(input_file=file, table='QUANT_work..test17')
```

Source:https://github.com/fivestack/bcp/issues/15